# For a continuous function on closed bounded interval is absolute minimum value, absolute maximum values are same as inf, sup of image set

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I was reading **theorem “5.3.9”** of “**Introduction to real analysis Robert G. Bartle and Donald R. Sherbert**”. **I didn’t not understand one step in the proof of theorem.** In a second line of proof author writes “ by “Maximum and minimum theorem 5.3.4” we have $m,M\in f(I)$. (Where, $m=\inf f(I)$, and $M=\sup f(I)$) How? Can anybody explain?

**My opinion**: By maximum minimum theorem, as $f$ is continuous on closed and bounded interval $I$ hence, $f$ has absolute minimum and absolute maximum on $I$. Hence by definition of absolute minimum, absolute maximum values we have, there exists points $c_*,c^*\in I$ Such that,

$f(c_*)≤f(x)$ for all $x\in I$ and $f(c^*)≥ f(x)$ for all $x\in I$ .

**So how author concluded** $m=\inf f(I),M=\sup f(I)\in f(I)$?

Is $m=\inf(f(I))=f(c_*)$ and $M=\sup(f(I))=f(c^*)$ and hence $m,M\in f(I)$?

Am I correct? Please help.

Comment: Yes. Do you know what inf and sup mean?

Comment: @RobertIsrael yes sir, i know, if set of lower bounds of set $S\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ has least element then it is called $inf S$ and similarly for $supS$.

Comment: Not quite.  $\inf S$ is the **greatest** lower bound of $S$.  So, is $f(c_*)$ a lower bound of $f(I)$?  Can any lower bound $> f(c_*)$?

Comment: @RobertIsrael sir, as $f(c_*) ≤f(x)$ for all $x\in I$ hence no lower bound of $f(I)$ can greater than $f(c_*)$. So it is greatest of all lower bounds of $f(I)$ and hence it is $inff(I)$ ? Am i correct sir?

Comment: @RobertIsrael sir, please reply...

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to apply the following fact to the set $A=f[I]$.$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb R}$

**Fact.** If $A$ is subset of $\R$ and if $m=\min A$, $M=\max A$ then $m=\inf A$, $M=\sup A$.

This is true for any partially ordered set, but since you are asking this in context of real analysis, I have only mentioned $A\subseteq\R$.

This simply says that if a set *has* maximum, then it is equal to supremum. (The same is true for minimum and infimum.) Notice that there are sets which have supremum, but do not have maximum - for example, $A=(0,1)$.

Why this claim is true - it depends a bit on how you defined maximum and minimum. But for any reasonable definition you should be able to see that if $M=\max A$, then

- $M$ is an upper bond of $A$, i.e., for any $a\in A$ you have $a\le M$.
- $M$ belongs to $A$, and thus for any upper bound $U$ of the set $A$ we have $M\le U$. (We have $a\le U$ for every $a\in A$. Since $M\in A$, the inequality is true for $M$, too.)